# Extract full extension of file path

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

Using `std::filesystem`, and given a path like `/path/to/file.tar.gz`, how may I extract the **full** or **complete** file extension - in this case `tar.gz`?

It appears that [`std::filesystem::extension()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) only returns the fragment after the last dot in the filename. With the path specified above the result would be `.gz`.

Qt provides [`QFileInfo::completeSuffix()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#completeSuffix) for this. Is there an equivalent in `std::filesystem` as per C++20?

Comment: Note the difference in names of the standard function and the Qt function: *extension* versus *suffix*. The *extension* is traditionally and commonly *only* the part after the last dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated method for this, but you could implement it with simple string operations:

```
std::filesystem::path path = "/path/to/file.tar.gz";
std::string filename = path.filename().string();
std::string extension(std::find(filename.begin(), filename.end(), '.'), filename.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux systems, you can have many dots in file paths. For example `/tmp/some.nice.looking....file.here.txt` is a valid file path. See also [path_resolution(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) and [file(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) and observe that a file path which is (in C notation) `"/\n"` is valid (but ugly) - at least inside some [ext4(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) file system.

Also, a file path could (by convention, or user mistake) contain spaces, tabs, or weird [UTF-8](https://utf8everwhere.org/) characters. Think of some USB key with some VFAT file system written on a Windows laptop used by a Russian mathematician writing some paper in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) about [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) - he/she could name the `.tex` file with λ and his/her cyrillic family name.

And you could have some applications which define new *conventional* suffixes. For example, my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) uses `.bmon` extension by convention.

A possibility is to restrict your application (by documented convention) to handle extensions listed in `/etc/mime.types`

Then your application would parse, at startup time, that `/etc/mime.types`, and collect a set of possible file extensions.